# push docker image to ECR using terraform

Tags: docker, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, dockerhub

Using terraform to pull and reload an public image from Dockerhub (or just custom image) to ECR. I was thinking about something like

```
# Create ECR repository
resource "aws_ecr_repository" "ecr_repo" {
  name                 = var.ecr_name
}
# Docker image
resource "null_resource" "docker_hub" {
        ......
        ......
  depends_on = [aws_ecr_repository.ecr_repo]
}
```

Basically create an ECR repo and then uplodading an image...
I'm new to terrform and been spending quite a lot of time on this. so anything would help. Thanks

Answer (score 16):

Terraform was really only designed for creating infrastructure like the AWS ECR repository and policy document resources. It is possible to coerce Terraform to do what you want using the [local-exec provisioner](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/resources/provisioners/local-exec.html) which would let you add arbitrary commands, but it's not really best practice. As they mention in the documentation Terraform provisioners should be treated as a last resort.

The simplest way forward would be to just combine Terraform with Docker and AWS CLI commands to build and push the image:

```
# ...terraform commands    
docker build -t ${ACCOUNT}.dkr.ecr.${REGION}.amazonaws.com/${REPO} .

aws ecr get-login-password \
    --region ${REGION} \
| docker login \
    --username AWS \
    --password-stdin ${ACCOUNT}.dkr.ecr.${REGION}.amazonaws.com

docker push ${ACCOUNT}.dkr.ecr.${REGION}.amazonaws.com/${REPO}
```

Alternatively, you could use [HashiCorp Packer](https://www.packer.io/) which was designed for this purpose (building VM/container images) and has great integration with Terraform. This would mean more of a learning curve though, as Packer doesn't use Dockerfiles. Anyway, if you go down this path you'd need to use the [Docker builder](https://www.packer.io/docs/builders/docker) combined with the [Docker push post-processor](https://www.packer.io/docs/post-processors/docker/docker-push).

Comment: I agree with this answer. I just want to add that you could use the [Amazon ECR Credential Helper](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-ecr-credential-helper) and skip the `aws ecr get-login-password` step.

Comment: if you were to run the script above in a local-exec provisioner, how would you go about installing and running docker, which would be required to run that script?

Comment: also, how do you deal with authentication when running the aws cli command?

Comment: I second @Kappacake I dont get how to run this without docker

Answer (score 6):

### Use the `aws_ecr_authorization_token` data source to configure the Docker provider to read/push from AWS ECR.

This works *atleast* as of July 2023. See example terraform configuration file:

```
# tell terraform which provider plugins are needed
terraform {
  required_providers {
    docker = {
      source  = "kreuzwerker/docker"
      version = "3.0.2"
    }
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "5.6.2"
    }
  }
}

# configure aws provider
provider "aws" {}

# create ecr repo
resource "aws_ecr_repository" "my-ecr-repo" {
  name = "my-ecr-repo"
}

# get authorization credentials to push to ecr
data "aws_ecr_authorization_token" "token" {}

# configure docker provider
provider "docker" {
  registry_auth {
      address = data.aws_ecr_authorization_token.token.proxy_endpoint
      username = data.aws_ecr_authorization_token.token.user_name
      password  = data.aws_ecr_authorization_token.token.password
    }
}

# build docker image
resource "docker_image" "my-docker-image" {
  name = "${data.aws_ecr_authorization_token.token.proxy_endpoint}/my-ecr-repo:latest"
  build {
    context = "."
  }
  platform = "linux/arm64"
}

# push image to ecr repo
resource "docker_registry_image" "media-handler" {
  name = docker_image.my-docker-image.name
}
```

Comment: this doesn't work for me. Says  "Error: Error pinging Docker server: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?  provider 'docker' { ". Any ideas?

Comment: yes, that means docker is not running :) You need to turn on docker desktop or docker daemon from the command line if you don't have docker desktop.

Comment: Unfortunately i'm looking for a solution with Terraform Cloud not my local environment. And I've found everyone build their images outside of Terraform, so now i'm using Github Actions to do that.

Answer (score 3):

you would use the `aws_ecr_repository` resource as you have done, and any other resources you would like to use in the ECR AWS Provider. The one below is the aws_ecr_repository_policy to be able to set the permissions on the repository.

```
resource "aws_ecr_repository_policy" "demo-repo-policy" {
  repository = aws_ecr_repository.demo-repository.name
  policy     = <<EOF
  {
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
      {
        "Sid": "adds full ecr access to the demo repository",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": [
          "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
          "ecr:BatchGetImage",
          "ecr:CompleteLayerUpload",
          "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
          "ecr:GetLifecyclePolicy",
          "ecr:InitiateLayerUpload",
          "ecr:PutImage",
          "ecr:UploadLayerPart"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
  EOF
}
```

Afterwards you can use the attributes from the resources you have used, for the `docker push` command

`docker push ${aws_account_id}.dkr.ecr.${region}.amazonaws.com/${repository-name}`

more information in the following tutorial
https://www.oneworldcoders.com/blog/using-terraform-to-provision-amazons-ecr-and-ecs-to-manage-containers-docker